# Versionamento de .jar no Java com Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, versionamento

Eu gostaria que meu `.jar` possuísse um número de versão e data de release dentro dele, para que eu pudesse informar ele na tela de about por exemplo.

Até aí sem mistério, mas a questão é que a cada `build` no Netbeans eu queria que a versão fosse incrementada automaticamente, assim como sua data de release.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?
Haveria outra forma ou ferramenta que faz isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salve!

Eu utilizo o [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) para realizar a estrutura do meu projeto e a gestão de configuração. Ele é agnóstico ao IDE e sugere um meio para que o seu projeto tenha uma estrutura inteligente de organização de recursos e código.

Adicionalmente, há uma série de plugins que você pode realizar praticamente qualquer tarefa a respeito de estrutura de projeto, *deploy* e *release* de projeto. Enfim, é uma ferramenta poderosa. Sugiro que você dê uma olhada. O Netbeans [possui](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html) [suporte](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Maven).

Para gerar número de **build** eu utilizo o plugin [`buildnumber-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html). Ele se conecta ao seu repositório e gera um número baseado no `commit`. É bem interessante. Abaixo um exemplo que utilizo no meu projeto:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${build.number.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <getRevisionOnlyOnce>true</getRevisionOnlyOnce>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
        <shortRevisionLength>5</shortRevisionLength>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Nesse caso ele recupera os 5 primeiros dígitos do código de `commit` do meu repositório GIT e adiciona no manifesto. Acredito que com alguma configuração ele também possa adicionar essa informação no seu arquivo final.

Para configurar o link do seu repositório no projeto, basta adicionar na seção `scm` do seu `pom.xml`.